# Water bathing applesauce without the lid

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation

I water bathed applesauce did everything
Right except, I didn’t put on the lid when
I was water bathing the applesauce in the pot. It’s been about a month since I did this but, my question is are they ok? They all sealed.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the lid on the pot is not required.  What is required is for the water to be the right temperature.